# How to write the Android.mk script?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

```
jni/
    Android.mk     -> libmyso.so
    folder1/
        Android.mk  -> libso1.so
    folder2/
        Android.mk  -> libso2.so
```

How to compile the libso1.so and libso2.so into the libmyso.so? Thus, I can only load libmyso.so in the java code, and needn't load libso1.so and libso2.so respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `libso1.so` and `libso2.so` are dependencies of `libmyso.so` (e.g. declared via `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` in `Android.mk`, they will be loaded automatically on Android 5.0 - the fact that you need to load them in reverse order (loading first the dependencies, then `libmyso.so` itself) is only a limitation of the linker in old Android versions.

If you just want to have one single `.so` file that contains all the code, change the `Android.mk` for `libso1.so` and `libso2.so` to do `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` instead of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`, and refer to them via `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` instead of `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`. Then they will be built in and you only have one single `.so` file to distribute and load.

Comment: The second way, that's what I am doing. Thanks.